# Using Javascript how do I add an array that is an argument for a function/method to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, methods

I am attempting to match an array being passed through as arguments to a Javascript class method to an array of objects that are also being created within the method.

For example, here's an array being passed:

```
colorSet = ["red","orange","purple","yellow"]
```

When this array is passed in the below method called addColors, I need to create an object and push the object to an empty array based on the length of the colorSet. This is simple enough.

```
 addColors(colorSet) {
  let obj = {}
  for (let i = 0;i<colorSet.length;i++){
   this.legend.push(obj)
  }
```

However, after doing this, I attempted within the same for loop to add object key 'color' to the array of objects and set its value to the array of colors in colorSet. See below:

```
 addColors(colorSet) {
  let obj = {}
  for (let i = 0;i<colorSet.length;i++){
    this.legend.push(obj)
    this.legend[i].color = colorSet[i]
  }
```

However, here is the result:

```
0: Object { color: "yellow" }
​
1: Object { color: "yellow" }
​
2: Object { color: "yellow" }
​
3: Object { color: "yellow" }
```

What I want is this:

```
0: Object { color: "red" }
​
1: Object { color: "orange" }
​
2: Object { color: "purple" }
​
3: Object { color: "yellow" }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have `let obj = {};` line which is out side `for` loop and same object is being referred by all items that are pushed to `legend`. Move it inside for loop to fix this issue:

```js
var legend = [];

function addColors(colorSet) {
  for (let i = 0; i < colorSet.length; i++) {
    let obj = {}; // <- new object should be defined here
    legend.push(obj);
    legend[i].color = colorSet[i];
  }
}

addColors(["red", "orange", "purple", "yellow"]);
console.log(legend);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem. You're mutating the object `legend[i]` - but this, for all indices `i`, is a reference to the same object `obj`, with the result that mutating any one changes them all.

The solution: simply push a brand new object each time, without mutating anything:

```
addColors(colorSet) {
  for (let i = 0;i<colorSet.length;i++){
    this.legend.push({ color: colorSet[i]});
  }
}
```

In fact, you could simplify this by removing the loop and just using the `map` method and rest parameters:

```
addColors(colorSet) {
  this.legend.push(...colorSet.map(color => ({ color })))
}
```

Comment: This worked great. But I found out I have to use this solution with a method that comes before this one. So now I have an object that looks like this: 

0: Object { indicator: "first datapoint" }
​
1: Object { indicator: "second datapoint" }
​
2: Object { indicator: "third datapoint" }
​
3: Object { indicator: "fourth datapoint" }

So I have to add the array of colors to this, but I am running into the same issue where only the last color in the array is being added to the object. 

Here is where I'm stuck:
this.legend.map(o=>colorSet.forEach(color=>{
   o.color = color
 })
 )

Comment: Just figured it out using a for loop: 

 for (let i =0;i<colorSet.length;i++){
   this.legend[i].color = colorSet[i]
 }

Answer (score 0):

On `addColors`, the problem is you are pushing `obj` variable on for loop.
On `legend.push(obj)`, it pushes the reference of `obj` variable, not the value of `obj` so all variables are set as `last-index` value.

```js
const colorSet = ["red", "orange", "purple", "yellow"];

function addColors(colorSet) {
  const legend = [];
  for (let i = 0;i< colorSet.length; i++) {
    legend.push({}); // - Here, instead of pushing `obj`, push initial value `{}`
    legend[i].color = colorSet[i];
  }
  
  console.log(legend);
}

addColors(colorSet);
```

Simply, this can be done using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const colorSet = ["red","orange","purple","yellow"];

const result = colorSet.map((item) => ({ color: item }));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create the object in the loop.

Link this.

```
function addColors(colorSet) {
  const legends = [];
  for (let i = 0;i<colorSet.length;i++){
  const obj = {
    color: colorSet[i]
  }
   legends.push(obj)
  }
  
  console.log(legends)
  
 }

const colorSet = ["red","orange","purple","yellow"];


addColors(colorSet);
```